# is there a "fault-tolerant" or "loose" mode for @babel/parser?

Tags: babeljs, fault-tolerance

I'm interested in using @babel/parser to parse a Javascript source file which may or may not contain syntax errors.  [`acorn-loose`](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/tree/master/acorn-loose) is a thing, and [`esprima`](http://esprima.org/) can be passed a `tolerant` flag with a value of `true`; is there an equivalent for babel 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that Babel's parser currently supports.